# can't login in HTML page which loaded in android webview

Tags: android, html

Hello friends I have one android WebView  app. in that app I have loaded particular URL. 
the problem is that web-page have login page when press login it returns the same login page again . 
anybody tell me how to solve this problem

here is my mainactivity

-

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
      public WebView webView;

```
  @SuppressLint("JavascriptInterface")
  @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
  @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
      webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.web);
      progressBar = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
      webView.setWebViewClient(new overload());
      setProgressBarVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
      Context context;

      webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
          @Override
          public void onReceivedSslError(final WebView view, final SslErrorHandler handler, final SslError error) {
              handler.proceed();
          }
           @Override
          public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favion){
              super.onPageStarted(view,url,favion);
              setProgressBarVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

          }
          @Override
          public void onPageFinished(final WebView view, String url) {
              //hide loading image
              findViewById(R.id.imageLoading1).setVisibility(View.GONE);
              //hide progressbar
              setProgressBarVisibility(View.GONE);
              //show webview

              findViewById(R.id.web).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);





          }
      });
        webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");



    // webView.loadUrl("https://192.168.0.186:8443/");//wifi
     // webView.loadUrl("https://192.168.1.6:8443/");//Ethernet
      //webView.loadUrl("https://192.168.1.12:8443/");//ethernet
      webView.getSettings().setRenderPriority(WebSettings.RenderPriority.HIGH);
      // webView.loadUrl("javascript:var footer = document.getElementById(\"footer\");       footer.parentNode.removeChild(footer); ");
     // webView.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { " + "document.getElementById('Footer').style.display='none';"+"})()");
      WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
      if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
          webSettings.setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
      }
      webSettings.setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
      webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

      webSettings.setSupportMultipleWindows(true);




      webSettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);


  }

  private void setProgressBarVisibility(int visible) {
      if (progressBar != null){
         progressBar.setVisibility(visible);
      }
  }

  public class overload extends WebViewClient{
      @Override
      public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
          view.loadUrl(url);

          return true;
      }    }







  @Override
  public void onBackPressed()
  {
      if (webView.canGoBack()){webView.goBack();}
      else{

          new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this,R.style.AlertDialogStyle)
                  .setMessage("Are you sure you want to exit?")
                  .setCancelable(false)
                  .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                      public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                          MainActivity.this.finish();
                      }
                  })
                  .setNegativeButton("No", null)
                  .show();
         // super.onBackPressed();
          }
  }


  }
```

this is my html file

```
<html>   <body>    <div>   <object type="text/html"      
   data=url    width=100% height=100% >         
   </object>   </div>


            </body> </html>
```

Comment: any error message?

Comment: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'historyLengthAtStart' of null"

Comment: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'roleTypeId' of null"